# Upgrade remote FreeBSD server no KVM

Tags: freebsd

Environment:

- Remote dedicated server
- FreeBSD 9.1-release with custom kernel [quota,ipfirewall,ipfirewall_default_to_accept]
- SSH access
- No easy KVM access (only accessible by my provider)

Goal:

- Upgrade to FreeBSD 9.2-release (for a start then... to 10.1...)

Reason:

- Freebsd 9.1-release is supported only until Dec 30 2014

Question:

How to upgrade FreeBSD 9.1-RELEASE to 10.1-RELEASE for instance, using `freebsd-update` or rebuilding the kernel and world, knowing that the server can't be accessed after being rebooted in single user mode because of the remote situation.

I read about **kern.securelevel** set to 2 to allow installing the world without being in single user mode, what to think about it?

How to upgrade the kernel from 9.2 sources without the 9.1 base system (it breaks, CC header problem)?

How would you proceed?

Comment: I googled for a solution for hours without getting something concrete except few ideas to explore. There must be something "square" and safe to do... I keep digging... Thank for your message though.

Comment: It is fixed now, it was power management of USB messed up after the failed upgrade, i cleaned all the sources and build a new kernel with the options mentioned earlier (my provider had to request a KVM to be able to boot poorly).

Comment: Does this mean the problem of your question was solved by yourself in the meantime? In that case best swap your answer with what you did to succeed.

Comment: No it means that i followed the handbook and i'm still looking for the right way to upgrade the system without breaking something again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Situation solved** (was not easy) by booting on a precompiled kernel of 9.2-RELEASE with the needed kernel options. After a boot failure, in fact it's more because of hard drive file system problem, we managed to boot on this bloody kernel thru IP-KVM access.

So it's **possible to keep using a GENERIC kernel** and to avoid the firewall to block you right away because you don't have an hand (physically speaking) on the machine and do all that remotely.

**The solution** is to add these in */boot/loader.conf*

```
net.inet.ip.fw.default_to_accept="1"
ipfw_load="YES"
```

and in */etc/rc.conf*

```
quota_enable="YES"
```

No need to compile a new kernel for quota support either, i always thought it was the only way, good thing i was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Yes i did follow these instructions (http://freebsd.org/doc/handbook/updating-upgrading-freebsdupdate.html) but as explained, it failed to boot because of an irq16 storm ; there was a problem in the usb support then. Here is the result:

## `vmstat -i`

interrupt total rate 
irq1: atkbd0 9 0 
irq16: xhci0 ehci0 49440997 716 
irq23: ehci1 240726 3 
cpu0:timer 10114125 146 
irq264: re0 3166270 45 
irq265: ahci0 2493196 36 
cpu1:timer 4722048 68 
cpu6:timer 4767453 69 
cpu3:timer 5537583 80 
cpu7:timer 5928230 85 
cpu2:timer 6624744 96 
cpu4:timer 4985019 72 
cpu5:timer 5463323 79 
Total 103483723 1499

Answer (score 0):

This post from an [old thread](http://compgroups.net/comp.unix.bsd.freebsd.misc/single-user-and-kernel-panic/2265720) confirms my suspicion that there no such option because it would not be useful:

> > so, how can I make that there is no single user mode?
>
> You need to fix
>   the problem that's causing it to go into single user mode. For that
>   you need access to the box (..) Until
>   you can see where startup is failing you don't know what needs fixing.
>
> David

This assumes that the system only goes down into single user mode if some problem exists (corrupt file system, hardware trouble etc). Asking such to not happen is not possible mostly.

You might modify the system behaviour, after all you can modify it from source, e.g. here one might replace the single-user state `single_user` with `runcom`:
[init.c:383](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/release/9.1.0/sbin/init/init.c?view=markup#l383)

But then it is still a matter of luck, if the resulting system is usable or not.

Comment: I upgraded just now to 9.2-RELEASE ; i found a compiled kernel with the good options from the server provider, didn't reboot the machine yet, i'm crossing fingers...